# Gunicorn on Google Cloud Run get an 504 error status (Upstream Request Timeout)

Tags: gunicorn, google-cloud-run, fastapi, http-status-code-504, uvicorn

so I have code that at startup need to load the Machine Learning Model that got a 1 pickle about 100MB, in my case I need to load 6 pickle file (around 600mb++), and I use FastAPI for my API code with Uvicorn and Gunicorn.

So, what I want to ask is why my gunicorn always get a 504 error status code when I open my URL from Cloud Runabout 15 seconds for the first time, and after that the URL can be opened without an error. But after I leave it without opening the URL for about 30-60 minutes, it will return the 504 error again? Is my Gunicorn dead/shutdown? Because when i check it from my Cloud Run log, my gunicorn got a `Shutting down`, and I think my gunicorn was dead. So I need to keep my Gunicorn always on, but how can I make it to set my gunicorn always on?

This is how my pickle load :

```py
# Load all model
@app.on_event("startup")
async def load_model():
    # Pathfile
    pathfile_model = os.path.join("modules", "model/")
    pathfile_data = os.path.join("modules", "data/")

    start_time = time.time()

    # Load Model
    usedcar.price_engine_4w = {}
    top5_brand = ["honda", "toyota", "nissan", "suzuki", "daihatsu"]
    for i in top5_brand:
        with open(pathfile_model + f'{i}_all_in_one.pkl', 'rb') as file:
            usedcar.price_engine_4w[i] = pickle.load(file)
    with open(pathfile_model + 'ex_Top5_all_in_one.pkl', 'rb') as file:
        usedcar.price_engine_4w['non'] = pickle.load(file)

    # Load Dataset Match
    with open(pathfile_data + settings.DATA_LIST) as path:
        usedcar.list_match_seva = pd.read_csv(path)

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

    print("======================================")
    print("INFO  : Model loaded Succesfully")
    print("MODEL :", usedcar.price_engine_4w)
    print("ELAPSED MODEL TIME : ", elapsed_time)
```

Here are how my main.py code run :

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, log_level="info", loop=asyncio)
```

This is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev python3-pip git
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -U setuptools
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pi
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt --use-feature=2020-resolver
COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :8080 --workers 2 --threads 4 main:app --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornH11Worker --preload --timeout 60 --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm
```

This is my requirements for uvicorn and gunicorn :

```sh
fastapi
fastapi-utils
uvicorn[standard]
gunicorn
```

This is my Cloud Run Log :

```sh
2021-02-15 14:31:54.346 WIT [2021-02-15 07:31:54 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-02-15 14:31:54.385 WIT [2021-02-15 07:31:54 +0000] [11] [INFO] Shutting down
2021-02-15 14:31:54.386 WIT [2021-02-15 07:31:54 +0000] [12] [INFO] Shutting down
2021-02-15 14:31:54.486 WIT [2021-02-15 07:31:54 +0000] [11] [INFO] Waiting for application shutdown.
2021-02-15 14:31:54.486 WIT [2021-02-15 07:31:54 +0000] [11] [INFO] Application shutdown complete.
2021-02-15 14:31:54.486 WIT [2021-02-15 07:31:54 +0000] [12] [INFO] Waiting for application shutdown.
2021-02-15 14:31:54.486 WIT [2021-02-15 07:31:54 +0000] [11] [INFO] Finished server process [11]
2021-02-15 14:31:54.487 WIT [2021-02-15 07:31:54 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2021-02-15 14:31:54.487 WIT ======================================
2021-02-15 14:31:54.487 WIT INFO : Model loaded Succesfully
2021-02-15 14:31:54.487 WIT ELAPSED MODEL TIME : 13.514873743057251
2021-02-15 14:31:54.487 WIT INFO : Master Data Updated Succesfully
2021-02-15 14:31:54.487 WIT ELAPSED DATABASE TIME : 0.5247213840484619
2021-02-15 14:31:54.487 WIT ======================================
2021-02-15 14:31:54.487 WIT [2021-02-15 07:31:54 +0000] [12] [INFO] Application shutdown complete.
2021-02-15 14:31:54.487 WIT [2021-02-15 07:31:54 +0000] [12] [INFO] Finished server process [12]
2021-02-15 14:31:54.487 WIT [2021-02-15 07:31:54 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
```

As we can see, from my cloud run log, my gunicorn was shutdown suddenly.

And this is my Error :

[image: 1]
[image: Screenshot from 2020-12-15 16-34-03]

After I looked around, I've tried a few things like:

1. `--worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm` (I use this line because I think there might be blocking from my Docker Container, so I add this line to make sure there's no blocking from Docker Container, but it still gets a 504 status). [Source 1](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/gunicorn-in-docker/) [Source 2](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-avoid-gunicorn-excessively-blocking-in-os-fchmod)
2. `--preload` (I use this because I think my cloud run need to save some RAM to start my Gunicorn fastly, in case if my Gunicorn shutdown, then when I load my page again, it will load faster, but it still doesn't effect). [Source](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#preload-app)
3. I used my `worker=2`, `thread=4`, `graceful_timeout=100`, but it still makes my Cloud Run shutdown.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

By default Cloud Run is fully managed, what means that the number of instances will be automatically scaled to zero. The next request will trigger the start of a new instance. In this moment your Docker image will be loaded and initialized. This process takes time and is called the *warmup process*. In your case the process takes more time than your configured requests timeouts.

You have different possibilities to improve the process:

- Make your Docker image smaller (e.g. `*-alpine` as base images)
- Clean caches of `apt` and `pip`
- Remove `gunicorn` and scale by Cloud Run
- Use for each model a Cloud Run service (orchestration of microservices)

No good idea:

- You can still keep one instance alive with [`--min-instances`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--min-instances)

Comment: So, gunicorn configuration doesn't give any effect to my startup load?

Comment: `gunicorn` is lightweight. In your position I would test different webservers and scaling plans (web workers, num instances, ...). But don't forget to track the used memory to avaoid OOM (out of memory) errors.